# How to echo stuff from an array generated $actsAs = array('Containable');

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have read the guide on [CakeBook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) about the Containable array.

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

The result is:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Post' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'title' => 'This is the first post',
            'slug' => 'this-is-the-first-post',
            'body' => 'body body 111body body 111body body 111body body 111body body 111body body 111body body 111',
            'image_id' => '0',
            'language' => 'sv',
            'translation_id' => '0',
            'created' => '2012-09-03 17:45:57',
            'modified' => '2012-09-03 19:12:21'
        ),
        'Image' => array(
            'id' => null,
            'name' => null,
            'url' => null,
            'alt' => null,
            'description' => null
        ),
        'Asset' => array(),
        'Readmore' => array(),
        'Reference' => array(),
        'Category' => array(),
        'Course' => array(),
        'Tag' => array(),
        'User' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'password' => '*****',
                'id' => '2',
                'username' => 'test0',
                'fullname' => 'Test Test',
                'url' => '',
                'email' => '',
                'role' => 'admin',
                'phone' => '+',
                'created' => '2012-09-03 17:44:22',
                'PostsUser' => array(
                    'id' => '1',
                    'post_id' => '1',
                    'user_id' => '2'
                )
            ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                'password' => '*****',
                'id' => '1',
                'username' => 'test1',
                'fullname' => 'Frank',
                'url' => '',
                'email' => '',
                'role' => 'admin',
                'phone' => '',
                'created' => '2012-09-03 17:41:25',
                'PostsUser' => array(
                    'id' => '3',
                    'post_id' => '1',
                    'user_id' => '1'
                )
            )
        )
    ),
```

But it doesn't work to print out specific parts of the array. So if I in the index view for Post, I write:

```
echo h($post['Post']['title']);
```

everything is fine, but when I try:

```
echo h($post['User']['fullname']);
```

it doesn't work. I get the point, that I have to loop through the Users when I have a hasmany and belgosto relation between post and user.

So how can I print all users associated to a post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks! I found a solution to it. I was a bit careless, I tried a solution to do it manually before and added a PostUser model and a controller for that model. Deleted them and everything works fine. Cake magic works again.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

`$post['User']` is a array of users, so, each user have a index, for instance, to get the `test0´s` fullname, you need to do the follow:

```
echo h($post['User'][0]['fullname']);
```

Try the follow to show all users fullname:

```
<?php
foreach($post['User'] as $user) { 
    echo h($user['fullname']);
});
```